# Android: Cancel Async-Task and restart it

Tags: android, asynchronous, tcpclient

I coded an app to connect to my server via tcp/ip. (took the original code from a tutorial, but changed it)

There I have an Async-Task where I connect to my Server and wait for messages.
So this Task will never stop.

I start it with:

```
conTask = new ConnectTask().execute("");
```

The Task looks like this:

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        if (isCancelled()) {
            Log.d("async", "ASYNC CANCELED!!!");
            return null;
        }

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {

            @Override
            public void reconnect()
            {
                Log.d("recon", "here i can try to reconnect");

                reConnect();
            }

            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                if (message.equals("connected"))
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        });

        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I try to reconnect, when the connection fails or breaks.
If this happens, my TcpClient-Instance calls the reconnect()-Method where I call the reConnect()-Method from my Mainclass, where I try to kill the Async-Task and restart it:

```
    conTask.cancel(true);
    conTask = null;

    // disconnect
    mTcpClient.setMRun(false);
    mTcpClient.stopClient();
    mTcpClient = null;

   conTask = new ConnectTask().execute("");
```

It works fine, but suddenly while reconnecting, the App stops running and I don't know why. It repeatingly calls the reconnect-Method, for example if WLAN is off. And it works if I turn it on fast. But if I wait too long, the app is already crashed.

So my final question is: How do I stop an Async-Task from within and restart it? Obviously I do something wrong.

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but in your case, you should not use Asynctask for waiting too long. "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html said that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the fact that you only call `if (isCancelled())` at the beginning of `doInBackground()`.

I would assume that you would like it to successfully cancel when the `reconnect()` method is called right?

In that case try encapsulating all the contents of your `reconnect()` method in an `if (ConnectTask.this.isCancelled() != true)` and then you can choose to return from the method otherwise.

Comment: But how does the .isCancelled()-Value gets false?

Comment: You have to keep a strong reference to the `AsyncTask` object you created, like so `ConnectTask temp = new ConnectTask ();` then `temp.execute();` and then somewhere down the line (say at the click of a button) call `temp.cancel(true);`

Comment: Yeah but it should be canceled when reconnect() is called...so i am a bit confused

Comment: Hmm I understand the confusion. Its really difficult to kill and restart the AsyncTask from within it because the class is designed to be used just once. This means that if you wish to reuse the logic within it, you would need to make another instance of `ConnectTask`.  May I suggest you instantiate your TCP object elsewhere (maybe in the parent activity or service?) so that it remains slightly independent of the AsyncTask? That way you may be able to recreate the task.

Answer (score 0):

Actually from your code doing `AsyncTask.cancel()` will not do any good. This method will cause `isCancelled` to return true and it is supposed to serve as a loop breaker in `doInBackground`. You are not running any loop and your code will not go back to that condition check.

So if I were you I would first assess the need to have AsyncTask because it looks you just use it to start `mTcpClient`. And by the looks of it, it already runs asynchronously because you have callbacks attached. AsyncTask *is* Asynchronous Task so there's no point of wrapping AsyncTask on something that is already running asynchronously. And clearly the original goal is not to cancel AsyncTask but to stop this thing. If an AsyncTask is indeed required then I would limit the lifetime of the process inside. I would not use an asynchronous but synchronous method to deliver a result to `onPostExecute` or just end it in `doInBackground`. In the case of cancellation not possible then the only thing to do to cancel an AsyncTask is to let it end by itself.